# Django filtering a queryset -

Tags: django, django-queryset

What I am trying to do is to write a query set that filters out unique parent/name combinations.  I'm only interested in the first occurance of a unique parent name.

```
ID   PARENT TYPE       LIBTYPE NAME
1     1     project     1     book_a
4     4     project     2     book_b
5     4     project     2     book_c
6     4     project     2     book_d
7     4     project     4     book_c
8     5     project     2     book_e
9     5     project     4     book_e
10     7     project     0     book_f
11     7     project     0     book_g
12     7     project     6     book_h
13     6     user        1     book_i
14     6     project     1     book_j
15     6     project     1     book_k
16     7     project     5     book_h
17     7     project     8     book_h
18     7     project     7     book_h
19     7     project     9     book_h
20     7     project     1     book_h
21     8     project     1     book_a
```

So we started with a basic queryset..

```
vars = Variants.objects.filter(type="project")
```

This removed out the lone user..  Now in pure python I would just do this to filter this sucker.

```
vars = Variants.objects.filter(type="project")
new_vars = []
for idx, var in vars.enumerate():
    if var.name not in new_vars:
        new_vars.append((var.parent,var.name))
    else:
        del vars[idx]
```

In the end I should end up with the following ID's (1,4,5,6,8,10,11,13,14,15,21)  Obviously I can't enumerate on a Queryset plus I'm sure there is a way to filter this in Django.

Can someone please shed some light on how to efficiently do this in Django?

Comment: An unrelated small tip: I would avoid using `vars` as a variable/function name as it overrides a builtin function. See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your so-called "pure Python" solution makes no sense, I'm afraid. For a start, `enumerate` is a built-in, so you would call `enumerate(vars)`; secondly, you append a tuple to new_vars so `var in new_vars` will never be True; and thirdly, I can't see what you're trying to do with that `del` statement - you should never modify something you're iterating through.

A better solution in Python might be something like this:

```
var_dict = {}
for var in vars:
    if var.name not in var_dict:
        var_dict[var.name] = var

return var_dict.values()
```

which works just as well with a queryset.

If I understand correctly, though, you're after a db-level solution. That's not possible, as aggregation functions work on the whole row being selected. You can get the unique values for `(parent, name)` but you can't get the ID as well - because `(id, parent, name)` is not a unique combination.

Comment: Too little sleep - I am so embarrassed.  I appreciate you wasting your time to show me - I just also realized the gross errors.  Accepting and closing.  Thanks Dan!  FWIW - the uniqueness was based on both the name, and the parent, not simply the name.  Regardless I don' tneed anymore assistance - nor do I deserve it.

Comment: Don't be so hard on yourself! This forum is for asking questions, and this is far from a bad question or lack of effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did do - Dan was right and I was a bone-head..

```
projects = Variant.objects.filter(type="project")
filter_list, uniq_projs = [], []
for project in projects:
    if (project.name, project.parent) not in uniq_projs:
        uniq_projs.append((project.name, project.parent))
        filter_list.append(project.id)
projects = Variant.objects.filter(type="project", id__in=filter_list).order_by('parent__name')
```

Feeling so dumb..